# Nested Radicals Induction

Tags: induction, nested-radicals

How can I show that $\sqrt[2]{2+\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt[4]{4+\cdots}}} $ (repeated $n$ times) is irrational using induction?

I know the base case for $n=1$ looks like: $\sqrt[2]{2}$ is irrational.

I also know that I need to assume it is true for an arbitrary $n$ and show that it is true for $n+1$. That is where I get stuck.

Can I use the fact that $\sqrt[n]{n}$ is irrational, $n\geq 2$?

Comment: I think you can use that fact: Since $\sqrt[n]{n}$ is irrational it follows that $(n-1)+\sqrt[n]{n}$ is irrational too. And a $n$-th root of an irrational number is irrational. (If it was rational you could take the $n$-th power of that rational number and you had the original number which must be rational too. Contradiction.) This should do it?

Comment: Yes, it looks awkward. The first thing to do is to look carefully at what happens for some small values of $n$. You need some notation. What do you suggest?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the $n$th element would be $f_n(2)$ where $$f_n(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
\sqrt[x]{x}&\quad\text{ if }n=0\\
\sqrt[x]{x+f_{n-1}(x+1)} &\text{ if }n\ne0\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Answer (score 0):

After proving that $n^{1/n}$ is irrational, prove the following stronger statement by induction on $r$:

If $n_1, n_2, \dots, n_r$ are positive integers, $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_r$ are positive rational numbers, and $x$ is a positive irrational number, then the number
$$\large \sqrt[n_r]{a_r+\sqrt[n_{r-1}]{a_{r-1}+\dots \sqrt[n_1]{a_1 + x}}} $$
is irrational.