# A question about a limit involving nested radicals

Tags: limits, nested-radicals

$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}1＋\sqrt{2+\sqrt[3]{3＋…\sqrt[n]{n}}}$$

Any hint will be appreciated

Comment: Probably not much help, but related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929156/nested-radicals-induction  Still, you might have a look at other questions with the nested-radicals tag.

Comment: Okey，I will take a look.

Comment: I can show that the sequence converges and give an upper estimate of the limit, but no idea about the exact value of the limit.

Comment: Duplicate: [$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}1+\sqrt{\vphantom{3}2+\sqrt[3]{\vphantom{H}3+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{\vphantom{3}n}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1633066/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/)*)

Answer (score 0):

The limit exist (since the sequence is increasing and bounded), but it has probably no close form.

By matlab,

```
function [f]=fxy(x,y)

if x==1
    f=y^(1/y);
else
    f=(y+fxy(x-1,y+1))^(1/y);
end
```

and

```
format long

for n=1:1:20
    f(n)=fxy(n,1);
end

plot(f,'o')
```

give the graph :
[image]

and we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n,1)\approx2.911639216245824$$

[read more](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-calculate-lim-limits_-n-to-infty-1+-sqrt-2-2+-sqrt-3-3+-dotsb+-sqrt-n-n-Please-explain)